# python simulation of actual number of occurrence given theoretical probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, simulation, probability

The goal is to simulate the actual number of occurrence given theoretical probabilities.

For example, a 6-faces biased dice with probability of landing (1,2,3,4,5,6) being (0.1,0.2,0.15,0.25,0.1,0.2).
Roll the dice for 1000 times and output simulated number of getting each face.

I know numpy.random.choices offer the function to generate each rolling, but I need kind of summary of number of landing of each face.
What is the optimal scripts with Python for above?

Comment: For the summary, `collections.Counter` is probably best. For the rolling, `random.choices` should work, no numpy needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. When looking for tools or library functions, it helps to know proper names for things. For example, do you know what a *histogram* is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Numpy** can be used to do that easily and very efficently:

```py
faces = np.arange(0, 6)
faceProbs = [0.1, 0.2, 0.15, 0.25, 0.1, 0.2]        # Define the face probabilities
v = np.random.choice(faces, p=faceProbs, size=1000) # Roll the dice for 1000 times
counts = np.bincount(v, minlength=6)                # Count the existing occurrences
prob = counts / len(v)                              # Compute the probability
```

Comment: FYI: `v` contains only small positive integers, so an efficient alternative to `histogram` is `bincount`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without Numpy too.

```
import random
random.choices([1,2,3,4,5,6], weights=[0.1,0.2,0.15,0.25,0.1,0.2], k=1000)
```